# Dynamic array storing values

Tags: c++

I resized my array with a function, however it seems like it does not store any array value I entered.

basically I put -1, the loop stops and then supposed to show the elements in array. but it does not show anything.

The output does not show anything after cout.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void resize(int *&arr, int &size){
    int tempsize=size;
    size=size+10;
    int *temp= new int [size];
    for(int i=0; i<tempsize;i++){
        temp[i]=arr[i];
    }
    delete [] arr;
    arr=temp;    
}

int main()
{
    int size=0;
    int capacity =10;
    int *p=new int[capacity];
    int check=0;
    int input;

    cout<<"Please enter the number in array and input -1 to end it.";

    while(check!=-1)
    {
        cin>>input;
        if(input==-1)
            {check=-1;}
        else{
        if(size==capacity){
            resize(p,capacity);
            p[size]=input;
            size++;
        }
        }

    }

    cout<<"Show me the numbers in array: ";

    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
        cout<<p[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    delete [] p;


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really have to work with raw arrays? This would be much easier to achieve with STL.

Comment: @ScepticalJule telling raw beginners to work with the stl is hardly helpful. if he doesn't understand the basics of arrays, he's been learning for about 10 minutes. This is clearly a learning exercise, and no way is he ready to learn the stl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement whether you need to resize the array is too encompassing. The {} should contain just the resize, then outside the {} is when you should store into the array.

Instead, size is 0, which != capacity, so you don't do anything.

Comment: This answer it too cryptographic to me

Comment: @Amadeus cryptographic? Perhaps you mean confusing? Look at his if(size == capacity) code block. He only adds to the array if a resize is required.

Comment: I'm sorry, this was a kind of sarcasm to say that your answer is too dificult to undersand. It would be easier if you shows in code what do you really means or want to say in words

Comment: It worked out Joseph, i put input and size++ right below cin>>input;